# Gmap looses GListener after refresh

Tags: c#, google-maps, subgurim-maps

I have a Gmap Control where i add lots of points(markers) via c# code.
Directly after i add the marker i add a GListener to all the markers.

Now i have a  few buttons on the web page that when a user clicks one of them the map gets refreshed to show only relative markers.
Everything works fine when the user clicks the first button but when the user clicks on any other button the Glistener just doesnt work but the markers does change accordingly.

Here is some code where i add the markers and listeners.

```
marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(lat, lng), new GIcon(Gicon));                 
clicklistener = new GListener(marker.ID, GListener.Event.click, string.Format(@"function(){{var w=new google.maps.InfoWindow();w.setContent('<center><b>{0}</b></center></br><center>{3}</center></br><center>{4}</center></br><center>{5}</center></br><center>{6}</center>');w.open({1}, {2});}}", SName + " , " + FacType, GMap1.GMap_Id, marker.ID, "Printer Status: " + PrinterStatus.ToString() + ", Battery: " + Sbat + "V  Signal: " + SSignal + "%", "Scanner Status: " + ScannerStatus.ToString(), "SMS Received: " + Sreceived + " , SMS Sent: " + Ssent, "Last SMS Date: " + SsmsDate.ToString() + " , Last Comms Date: " + ScommsDate.ToString()));
```

The Marker and clicklistener is globally defined and gets added to the map via gmap1.add(marker) and gmap1.add(clicklistener)
any ideas?

Regards
Patrick

Comment: That is [Google Maps Javascript API v2 code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference). The Google Maps JavaScript API Version 2 was officially deprecated on May 19, 2010. The original deprecation period has been extended from May 19, 2013 until November 19, 2013.  New development should really be done in the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics)

Answer (score 0):

Sorted.

All that needed to be done is a complete reset of the whole map like so:
        GMap1.reset();
and then just add the new markers and listeners as necessary :)